# Edit the code in the opened tab

Tags: javascript, cloud9-ide, cloud9

im doing a plugin to the cloud 9 sdk its basically a simple autocomplete for c language

my issue is that when i complete the name of the function the ide doesn't reserve the change meaning the next time he edit the line it will go back to before the line was edited

for example if i write `pri` then selected `printf` then pressed space it will be `"pri "` not `"printf "`

here is [my code](https://github.com/robertIsaac/cs50SimpleAutoComplete/blob/master/cs50SimpleAutoComplete.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what i found

```
ace.scrollTo(row, column);
clipboard.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", "text to add");
clipboard.paste();
```

you will need to include `clipboard` and `ace` to consumes for that code to work

Answer (score 0):

modifying html inside ace won't work.
If you want to create a new completer, create a lnaguage handler
https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/customizing-code-completers
which will use built in completer popup

Comment: i find a solution, coping my text to clipboard and then ask it to paste it :D

Comment: but if you can write a code to do that i will really appreciate it, cause my code just add not remove text